# Local instance of gitlab does not respond to REST-calls from the API documentation located in "/gitlab/doc/api/v4"

Tags: api, rest, curl, gitlab, http-status-code-404

I have undertaking a master thesis project that uses the `openapi.yaml` files to auto generate test for REST-api web-services - This has lead me to host a local instance of gitlab, so that I can run the tool I am working on, on gitlab. For that to happen I need the `.yaml` files containing the documentation for the API calls. Such files are found within in the gitlab source-code, but the call does not seem to work.

Some calls work, namely:

`http://localhost/api/v4/version`
`http://localhost/api/v4/users`
`http://localhost/api/v4/projects`
`http://localhost/api/v4/groups`

all returns meaningful JSON.

the problem is that a lot of the calls within the documentation does not work (returns a "404 not found"), namely:

`http://localhost/api/v4/metadata`
`http://localhost/api/v4/projects/{id}/access_tokens`

and more calls specified in the documentation.

The problem is that a lot of the calls that work are not documented (all of the above except the 'version' call). I have really tried to look for an alternative `openapi.yaml` files, but with little success and I am also puzzled to why the one left in the actual source-code does not contain meaningful documentation. Have I overlooked something? I am currently using postman and providing a sudo authentication-token.

Thanks in advance - I must surely have overlooked something!

Currently I have tried to look for an alternative `openapi.yaml` both by googling and be browsing swaggerhub.com. I Have look at the documentation pages for gitlab, but I have not found anything I did not already have.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at this time of writing, GitLab does not provide an OpenAPI spec for all of its API. Only a very small part of the API is documented in [openapi.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml). There is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16023) that is tracking this improvement.

For now, the online [API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/api_resources.html) are going to be your best source of information available on using the GitLab API.

As for your problem of getting `404` responses, the most common cause of this is that the credentials you are using do not have permissions to the project/feature you are trying to access or you are not using a proper [authentication method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication). Also keep in mind some features of the API require an appropriate license entitlement.

Comment: `GitLab does not provide an OpenAPI spec for all of its API` is a vast understatement, it's more like 90% of the API is not in the current openapi.yml ^^

Comment: @juwens yes, as I mentioned `Only a very small part of the API is documented`.

Comment: you are totally correct, i only wanted to emphasize your really good answer :)